# solr, sunspot_rails and faceting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

If anyone out there has experience with solr and/or sunspot_rails, I'd be forever grateful for any assistance re: the following:

In my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable  do 
    text :name
    text :employer
    text :city
  end
end
```

I'd like to be able to do something to the effect of:

```
@search = User.search { keywords 'Some-name' }
```

And then:

```
@search.facet(:city)
```

To retrieve my distinct city matches in the result set.

The only examples I've seen on the web (an lo, I've seached far and wide) facet across associations, i.e., if I were to move category and employee into associations and facet on category_id or employee_id.

My question is this - is it possible to facet on a text colum via sunspot_rails?

Thanks in advance for shedding some light on this for me!

Answer (score 1):

Just use a string field, rather than a text field.

Comment: Flipped text to string in searchable but still not getting anything out of my facets. May be missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 1):

Per outoftime - changed text to string, reimplemented as:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    string :name
    string :employer
    string :city, :multiple => true
  end
end
```

Now able to fire off:

```
User.search do
  keywords 'cory'
  facet :city
end
```

And pull back faceted results.